# how it possible.? add runtime dropdown text and value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Mr. Los Frijoles plz show my question and answer.
How it possible.? 
I have 2 drop down , 1st is static 'drpDisplayAns1' and 2nd is 'drpCorrectAns1' here i select 'drpDisplayAns1' option 2 then i get only 1 and 2 in 'drpCorrectAns1' my 2nd drop down, or i select 3 then i get only 1, 2 and 3 in 'drpCorrectAns1' my 2nd drop down, or i select 4 then i get 1, 2, 3 and 4 in 'drpCorrectAns1' my 2nd drop down.
means add runtime using jquery. or etc.
so how it possible.?
in Mvc Razor.
Plz Help Me.
thnks.

my view code is

```
         '<div class="editor-field">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DisplayAnswer, new SelectList(new[]
                                      {
                                          new { value="2", text="2"},
                                          new { value="3", text="3"},
                                          new { value="4", text="4"},
                                      }, "value", "text", 4), new{ id= 

   "drpDisplayAns1"})'
        '@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayAnswer)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label1">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer1)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer2)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label3">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer3)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer3)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer3)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer4)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer4)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer4)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer)
    </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer, new SelectList(new[]
                                      {
                                          new {value="0", text=" "},
                                          new {value="1", text="1"},
                                          new {value="2", text="2"},
                                          new {value="3", text="3"},
                                          new {value="4", text="4"},
                                      }, "value", "text", 0), new{id="drpCorrectAns1"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer)
    </div>'
```

and script file

```
'$(document).ready(function () {
$('#drpDisplayAns1').change(function () {

    if (this.value == '2') {
        $('.editor-label1').show();
        $('.editor-label2').show();
        $('.editor-label3').hide();
        $('.editor-label4').hide();
    }
    else if (this.value == '3') {
        $('.editor-label1').show();
        $('.editor-label2').show();
        $('.editor-label3').show();
        $('.editor-label4').hide();
    }

    else if (this.value == '4') {
        $('.editor-label1').show();
        $('.editor-label2').show();
        $('.editor-label3').show();
        $('.editor-label4').show();
    }
});
```

});'

Comment: Is the behavior you described the intended behavior or is it incorrect behavior and is what is currently happening? What is the result of your script?

Comment: my script is not use for "drpCorrectAns1". it only use of hide and show text box of Answer bcoz admin select display answer 2 then enter display only 2 text box and enter only two answer,

Comment: Los Frijoles i not ask a fake questions. and my question's answer is following. r u understand mr. Los Frijoles..??

Answer (score 1):

### Mr.Los Frijoles i not ask a fake questions.

and my question's answer is following.
r u understand mr. Los Frijoles..??

```
    <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DisplayAnswer, new SelectList(new[]
                                  {
                                      new { value="2", text="2"},
                                      new { value="3", text="3"},
                                      new { value="4", text="4"},
                                  }, "value", "text", 4), new{ id= 

"drpDisplayAns1"})'
    '@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayAnswer)
</div>
<div class="editor-label1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer1)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer1)
</div>
<div class="editor-label2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer2)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer2)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer2)
</div>
<div class="editor-label3">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer3)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer3)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer3)
</div>
<div class="editor-label4">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer4)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer4)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer4)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer, new SelectList(new[]
                                  {
                                      new {value="0", text=" "},
                                      new {value="1", text="1"},
                                      new {value="2", text="2"},
                                      new {value="3", text="3"},
                                      new {value="4", text="4"},
                                  }, "value", "text", 0), new{id="drpCorrectAns1"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer)
</div>
```

and my script code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#drpDisplayAns1').change(function () {

    if (this.value == '2') {
        $('.editor-label1').show();
        $('.editor-label2').show();
        $('.editor-label3').hide();
        $('.editor-label4').hide();
        $("#drpCorrectAns1 option[value='3']").attr("disabled", true).hide();
        $("#drpCorrectAns1 option[value='4']").attr("disabled", true).hide();
    }

    if (this.value == '3') {
        $('.editor-label1').show();
        $('.editor-label2').show();
        $('.editor-label3').show();
        $('.editor-label4').hide();
        $("#drpCorrectAns1 option[value='3']").attr("disabled", false).show();
        $("#drpCorrectAns1 option[value='4']").attr("disabled", true).hide();
    }

     if (this.value == '4') {
       $('.editor-label1').show();
       $('.editor-label2').show();
       $('.editor-label3').show();
       $('.editor-label4').show();
       $("#drpCorrectAns1 option[value='3']").attr("disabled", false).show();
       $("#drpCorrectAns1 option[value='4']").attr("disabled", false).show();
   }
});
```